# Monarch butterfly optimization algorithm Algorithm

Tags: python-3.x

Could anyone please, help me and share with me the Monarch butterfly optimization algorithm python(MBOA) code?

I tried to write the code but i have error with the result.If you have any specific guidelines or conditions regarding the sharing of the code, please let me know, and I will adhere to them.

Answer (score 1):

There is the MATLAB version of this algorithm :

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/101400-monarch-butterfly-optimization-mbo?s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_monarch%20butterfly

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55339-gcmbo?s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_2_monarch%20butterfly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).